# JIRA Rest API Notifications not Leaving Comments in Ticket

Tags: python, rest, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I'm currently using the JIRA Rest API to send a notification to a specified user. The problem is that if the user replies to the notification in the email it doesn't create a comment in the ticket. It just replies to the email of the user I'm logged in as. Anyone know how I can make email replies to my api notifications create JIRA comments? Here is my current code:

```
import requests

url = "https://jiraserver.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/{issue_key}/notify"

notify_data = {
        "subject": "Duis eu justo eget augue iaculis fermentum.",
        "textBody": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eget venenatis elit. Duis eu justo eget augue iaculis fermentum. Sed semper quam laoreet nisi egestas at posuere augue semper.",
        "htmlBody": "Lorem ipsum <strong>dolor</strong> sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eget venenatis elit. Duis eu justo eget augue iaculis fermentum. Sed semper quam laoreet nisi egestas at posuere augue semper.",
        "to": {
            "users": [
                {
                    "name": "JIRA user"}]
        },

    }

requests.post(url,auth=('jira_username','jira_password'), json=notify_data)
```

P.S. I am able to create comments in tickets if I reply to email notifications that I receive by manually updating an issue in JIRA (eg changing assignee) but not if I reply to the notification created through the API. Here is the API documentation that I used for notifications: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/issue-notify. Anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: Did you tried to extend the "to" field with something like "assignee": true,  and see if the assignee get notified?

Comment: For some reason assignee returns a 500 error, but "reporter":True, works. However replying to that email still doesn't create a comment in the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting I was able to resolve this issue by putting the Issue key in the subject, and setting up a listener on JIRA (settings cog -> system -> incoming mail -> Set up mail server and handler). This will cause replies to the jira notification to create comments.